# Is there a more efficient way to do this - Python For Loop Strings

Tags: python

I need to rearrange a string with this sequence:  2,4,6 ... 1, 3, 5 
For example 'Hello Joe' would become 'el oHloJ'
This is my code:

```
def encrypt(message):
    newMessage = []
    for i in range(1, len(message), 2):
        newMessage.append(message[i])
    for i in range(0,len(message),2):
        newMessage.append(message[i])

    print(newMessage)

encrypt("Hello Jo")
```

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What should happen if the given string has an uneven number of characters?

Comment: For uneven characters: input: 'end' output 'ned'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the `indexing` feature, like :

```
def encrypt(message):
    new_message = message[1::2] + message[0::2]
    print(new_message)

encrypt("Hello Jo")
```

Comment: He is basically doing the same thing you are doing with the `range` command. `'abc'[::2]` for example, will return `'ac'`. The third parameter when using `indexing` (just as `range`) is the "step" of the iterator. So when he say `[1::2]` He's saying: Start at index 1, go to the end of the string, and use a step-distance of 2.

Answer (score 1):

you can use string built-in indexing features like this
I hope this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
   In [2]: a ="Hello Jo"

    In [5]: a[1::2] + a[0::2]
    Out[5]: 'el oHloJ'
```

Hope it helps

first param in[::] is from where to start
where as last param in which next item to take.